# Variance of a uniform probability density function

Tags: statistics

> A normalized uniform distribution, $u(x)$, takes the value $\frac1{(b − a)}$ in the interval $a ≤ x ≤ b$ and is 0 otherwise. Calculate its variance.

I know that the variance can be given by: $\sigma^2=\langle x^2\rangle -\langle x \rangle$. So I decided to try and evaluate:

$$\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bx^2-\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bx=\sigma^2$$

However, unless my algebra is wrong, I get: $$\frac{2b^3-3b^2+3a^2-2a^3}{6(b-a)}$$

This doesn't look like it should be right. What have I done wrong?

Comment: $-\langle x \rangle$: This is wrong. It should be $-\langle x \rangle^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Other than that, is this the correct way to go about solving the problem

Comment: It is a correct way. Perhaps more work is to use the fact that $X=(b-a)U+a$ where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. Your method, corrected, shows that $U$ has variance $\frac{1}{12}$ and therefore $X$ has variance $(b-a)^2\cdot \frac{1}{12}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{Var} X=\operatorname EX^2-(\operatorname EX)^2$ for a random variable $X$ (you did not square the expected value). So we have that
\begin{align*}
\sigma^2
&=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bx^2\mathrm dx-\biggl(\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bx\mathrm dx\biggr)^2\\
&=\frac{b^3-a^3}{3(b-a)}-\biggl(\frac{b^2-a^2}{2(b-a)}\biggr)^2\\
&=\frac{b^2+ab+a^2}{3}-\biggl(\frac{b+a}2\biggr)^2\\
&=\frac{b^2-2ab+a^2}{12}\\
&=\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}.
\end{align*}